# Proxy Settings to access APEX Rest API

Tags: rest-api, apexrest

I have created the APEX Rest API (GET) to expose the Data to outside of Salesforce. When I access the API using the Postman I am getting the data without any error.

But when I had given my API to the external person he was not able to access it.He is getting some error and he says that we need to get proxy setting to bypass SSL issue

So what can be the proxy settings for this?

Please help
Thanks

Comment: Please share the actual error message. This could represent any one of a large number of issues.

Comment: The error which I am getting is { [Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND test.salesofrce.com at errorException (dns.js:28:10) 
at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:76:26)
code: 'ENOTFOUND',
errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
hostname: 'test.salesofrce.com',
host: 'test.salesofrce.com',
port: 443 }

Comment: They are getting a DNS error because they spelled 'salesforce' wrong. Nothing to do with proxies or SSL.

Comment: The spelling was right... it is my typo mistake here

Answer (score 1):

A proxy protects a network from the outside world. In other words, those settings are specific to the network being used. Consequently, we cannot help you with those settings. You must refer to your proxy's documentation or contact the IT department/help desk to get this type of help.

Comment: It is working perfectly fine for me if i call it through the Postman... but it is giving the above error when the external person is trying to access it

Comment: @NiravShah You are not the external person. You two are on different networks. Their network has a proxy, apparently. We can't help you fix their proxy issues.